# can make_unique store the literals or iostream inputs?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, smart-pointers

when I used the ordinary pointer of type char to store an input from `<iostream>` by `cin>>ptr`, it was converted to an array.

I deduced that because `cout<<ptr;` gives the stored string and does not give the address.And the address is given by `cout<<&pointer;`.

but when I used `make_unique` instead, it gave errors.
why do they behave the same.
Please, explain this and what is the proper way to store a string input as an array of characters using make_unique.
I have attached the used code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;
int main(){


//using of std::string
string str;
cout<<"Enter a str: ";
cin>>str;cout<<endl;
cout<<str<<"\n";


// using of ordinary pointer
char* str2;//as if u r assigning array to a pointer
cout<<"Enter a str: ";
cin>> str2;cout<<endl;
cout<<str2;
cout<<endl;

//using of arrays
char c[] = "ghfgtgbbb";
cout<<c;
char* cPtr = c;
cout<<"\n"<<cPtr;
cout<<endl;


//using of mak_unique (gives errors)
auto str3Ptr = make_unique<char>();
cout<<"Enter a str: ";
cin>> str3Ptr;cout<<endl;
cout<<str3Ptr;
cout<<endl;


return 0;}
```

Comment: Question: how many chars can be stored in the buffer provided by `str2`, `c` and `str3Ptr`?

Comment: as the user want@VTT

Comment: Note: I didn't mean "how many chars can user input", I wrote "how many chars can be stored".

Comment: yes I understood. as the user will write when he is asked for that. if he enters kkkkkk, the array will be of size 7 and so on@VTT

Comment: but str3Ptr does not work it gives errors. If it gets commented the code will work efficiently @VTT

Comment: Take a careful look at `str3Ptr`, how many chars it can store before `cin>> str3Ptr;`? Why would it all of it sudden be able to store 7 chars after a call `cin>> str3Ptr;`?

Comment: Please, note `str3Ptr` can't store the inputted string and on compiling the code without commenting `str3Ptr` related commnds, the code gives errors .But `cPtr` can store all the user enters and acts as an array. and I asked why don't they make the same thing @VTT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off,

```
// using of ordinary pointer
char* str2;//as if u r assigning array to a pointer
cout<<"Enter a str: ";
cin>> str2;cout<<endl;
cout<<str2;
cout<<endl;
```

might "work" but it is actually undefined behavior.  `char* str2;` creates a pointer that points to something, but we have no idea what.  Trying to store data in it with `cin>> str2` is undefined behavior as you have no permission to write to whatever `str2` points to.  So this block of code should be avoided.

Now lets look at

```
//using of arrays
char c[] = "ghfgtgbbb";
cout<<c;
char* cPtr = c;
cout<<"\n"<<cPtr;
cout<<endl;
```

This is better, `c` is an array of 10 characters and `cPtr` is initialized to point to it so it is a valid pointer.  You don't do input with it but you could but you have to make sure to take in no more than 9 character (you have to leave room for the null terminiator).

Now we will look at the `unique_ptr` code.  In

```
//using of mak_unique (gives errors)
auto str3Ptr = make_unique<char>();
cout<<"Enter a str: ";
cin>> str3Ptr;cout<<endl;
cout<<str3Ptr;
cout<<endl;
```

You have essentially done the same thing as you first code block.  `auto str3Ptr = make_unique<char>();`  Makes a unique pointer that points to a single `char`.  So at least you have initialized variable but it is not going to be big enough to store the input.  You would need to use the array version and allocate enough space for the input you want.  That would look like

```
auto str3Ptr = make_unique<char[]>(80);
                                   ^^ number of elements to allocate
```

You also can't use it with `cin` or `cout` as is as it doesn't provide overloads to do so.  You either have to write your own, or if there is an overload that works on the pointer type then you can use `get` to get an actual pointer to what is stored in the `unique_ptr`.

So, that leave us with

```
//using of std::string
string str;
cout<<"Enter a str: ";
cin>>str;cout<<endl;
cout<<str<<"\n";
```

Which is the proper way to deal with strings in C++.   It will handle the allocation and deallocation and is built to work with the standard streams.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.If the input inputted by `cin>>` is considered as an array of characters `cin>> str2;' shouldn't  be undefined behavior. But if not, what is it considered? @NathanOliver

Comment: @AsmM It's not anything because you didn't tell `str2` to point to anything.  If you want `str2` to point to an array then you need something like `char * str2 = new char[80];`

Comment: `char * str2 = defined_array_of_characters;` is a defined behavior so upon the literals (I am not sure If the input obtained by `cin>>` is considered as an array of characters.) is considered as  constant arrays which use pooling ..etc. Why is not `cin>>char * str2 ` defined.@NathanOliver

Comment: @AsmM because `char* str2;` doesn't have `str2` point to anything.  You have to have it point to something.  `cin` is going to allocate storage for you.

Comment: @asmmo: `cin >> str2` doesn't alter `str2` in any way.  That function takes the pointer you gave it and writes the input at whatever it points at. Since you didn't point `str2` at anything in particular, it points to a random address, and so that function will write the bytes to the random place in memory. This is undefined, it may kind of work, it may crash, it may erase files, or [print documents](https://nwn.blogs.com/nwn/2018/06/windows-second-life-yoz-linden-lab.html).